# print html in c# with invisible browser but with visible print dialog

Tags: c#, html, printing, browser

I want to print a html file, though i do not want the browser to be visible, but i want the print dialog to be visible.

Thanks,
Horea

Answer (score 1):

found the problem.
i have to wait for the event DocumentLoaded (or smt like that) to be fired, and then try the print.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, just hide the `WebBrowser` control on your form:

```
myWebBrowser.Visible = false;
```

Of course, you can also set this property in the Designer if you *never* want the control to be visible.